# Java Deployment in TorqueBox

Tags: java, torquebox

I am new to TorqueBox. I have created one RESTEasy app which is currently running on tomcat. Now I want to deploy it in TorqueBox.
For that I have created on yml file in apps folder of torquebox. The content of file is

```
---
application: 
  root: C:/torqueApp/java/RESTEasyTorque
  env: development 
web: 
  context: /hellojava
```

My problem is when i start server it doesn't deploy my app. What should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bob answered this on the mailing list, but I'll paste it here as well:

> You can deploy pure Java applications on TorqueBox, but you don't use
>   a torquebox.yml (or *-knob.yml).
>
> To deploy a Java application in TorqueBox, just drop your .war file
>   into the apps/ directory directly (I'm assuming TorqueBox 1.x)
>
> fwiw, if deploying a Ruby application, you can put a torquebox.yml
>   inside your application, but the files in app/ would be a *-knob.yml
>   file, or an archived version of your application with the extension of
>   .knob.
>
> When we refer to "knobs", we mean either the *-knob.yml, or the *.knob
>   archives, which are used in the apps/ folder.  torquebox.yml is
>   primarily used within your application's own directory tree.
>
> For Java applications, ignore everything TorqueBox-related, and you
>   can pretend that our distribution is just like JBoss AS6 (for
>   TorqueBox 1.x) or just like JBoss AS7 (for TorqueBox 2.x).  Our
>   changes are purely additive, building on top of the JavaEE container
>   from JBoss.

from: http://markmail.org/message/zhjwhbgxarjsvdz7

Answer (score 0):

For `torquebox-2.3.x` and above, you need to have jboss-clent.jar is available in your java app's library folder is automatically searches for running `JBOSS` instance and get deployed to it. However if you need to use Torquebox queues you to bind `JBOSS` to an `IP` using runtime `JVM` options e.g.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.bind.address=192.168.100.101 -Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.100.101 -Djboss.bind.address.unsecure=192.168.100.101
```

Then using JMS API you can use `Torquebox` `queues`